# Preventing phpunit from launching all functions

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

How to prevent phpunit from launching functions that I don't want?

```
<?php

namespace App\Tests;

use App\Core\Security\ModuleService;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class moduleTest extends WebTestCase
{
    /**
     * @var ModuleService
     */
    private ModuleService $moduleService;

    /**
     * moduleTest constructor.
     * @param ModuleService $moduleService
     */
    public function __construct(ModuleService $moduleService)
    {
        $this->moduleService = $moduleService;
    }
    
    public function testModule()
    {
        $modules = $this->moduleService->getAllModules();
    }
}
```

phpunit tries to test constructor method and crashes

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function App\Tests\moduleTest::__construct(), 0 passed in /vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestBuilder.php on line 138 and exactly 1 expected in /tests/moduleTest.php:20

Update

Tried doing it like this

```
public function setUp(ModuleService $moduleService) : void
    {
        $this->moduleService = $moduleService;
    }
```

But now I'm getting this error:

> ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function App\Tests\moduleTest::setUp(), 0 passed in /vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php on line 1126 and exactly 1 expected

Comment: I think what you are looking for is the SetUp function instead of a constructor.

Comment: @DirkScholten could you give me an example? I'm really new at phpunit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In tests you don't want to be using the constructor. Symfony will try to autowire service which you don't want because you want to be able to mock the secondary services.

To prevent this you remove the constructor and use the setUp function instead. PHPUnit works in such a way that the setUp function will always run before each test. So in here you would instantiate the service(class) you are testing.

A simple setUp function looks like this:

```
private ModuleService $moduleService;

public function setUp(): void
{
    $this->moduleService = new ModuleService();
}
```

Then afterwards in your tests you would use them like you normally would:

```
public function testStuff()
{
    $result = $this->moduleService->doStuff();
    $this->assertEquals('stuff', $result);
}
```

In case the service that you are testing has dependancies (which most services do), you should mock these like this:

```
private ModuleService $moduleService;
private MockObject $dependancyServiceMock;


public function setUp(): void
{
    $this->dependancyServiceMock = $this->createMock(DependancyService::class);
    $this->moduleService = new ModuleService($this->dependancyServiceMock);
}
```

This way the service that you are testing is isolated from any outside influences and you have full control over it without Symfony autowiring it or and other services doing stuff that you can't control.